# How to clear IE cache for one site by program

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, caching

I want to delete IE cache for one site, we know, we could use IE developer tool (Press F12) to delete a specific website.

However, I want to do this job by C++ program, but I don't know which cache files belong to the specific website.

I could clear all IE cache by deleting all files under IE temporary file directory. However, I don't know which files belong to a specific web site.

I have searched how to find the cache files of the web site two days, but have no any clue.

Do you have any suggestion about how IE developer tool knows this relationship?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Atleast post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for your remind, but I really don't have any idea about this  except google.

I just want to know how to find the cache files of a specific website under IE temporary file directory...

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C++ you can clear cache using the WinINet API

- FindFirstUrlCacheEntry
  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384026(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- FindNextUrlCacheEntry
  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384049(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- DeleteUrlCacheEntry
  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383983(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Basically you find the first entry, then enumerate all the entries using the next API and delete each one as you go (as needed). That's how the F12 developer tools clear the cache.